# how to parse line below so that it will preseve the third column as a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

how to parse this line using either pandas or CSV type module

```
col1, col2, col3 <br>
name, date, ["data"] <br>
name, date, ["data", "data2", "data3"]  <br>
name, date, ["data1", "data2"] <br>
```

this is the format of the file.

if I use

```
pd.read_csv(file)
```

I get this error

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 5
```

Comment: It may be that neither pandas nor csv can handle this. You could process the file yourself using a regular expression (re module) applied to each line. Also, does <br> exist as text in the file or is this just your way of indicating a line break?

Comment: This is not a legal csv file, so no true csv parser will be able to process it. I can only imagine one workaround: build a custom parser. But IMHO the real way is to carefully examine where that file comes from and fix its format in the previous step if possible.

Comment: sorry this is my first time asking question , and stack overflow was complaining about some formatting. so <br> is not an column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `delimiter=', (?![^\[]*[\]])'` to ignore comma between square brackets,

```
import io
data = '''col1, col2, col3 <br>
name, date, ["data"] <br>
name, date, ["data", "data2", "data3"]  <br>
name, date, ["data1", "data2"] <br>'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),delimiter=', (?![^\[]*[\]])', engine="python")
print(df)
```

---

**Output:**

```
   col1   col2                          col3 <br>
0  name   date                      ["data"] <br>
1  name   date   ["data", "data2", "data3"]  <br>
2  name   date            ["data1", "data2"] <br>
```

To remove `<br>`,

```
# To remove <br> tags from each line
df.rename(columns={'col3 <br>':'col3'}, inplace=True)
df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(' <br>', '').strip())

>>> output
   col1  col2                        col3
0  name  date                    ["data"]
1  name  date  ["data", "data2", "data3"]
2  name  date          ["data1", "data2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your third column contains data in string format, consider using `StringIO` and `converters` parameter which converts string representations into actually lists.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import ast

# Your data 
data = ...

# Coverting data into string representation
data_file = StringIO(data)

# Converter function to convert the string representation of lists to actual lists
def parse_list(s):
    return ast.literal_eval(s)

df = pd.read_csv(data_file, converters={'col3': parse_list})
print(df)
```

Comment: Test before posting the answer. This still gives the same error.

Comment: Opps ! My bad...

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep=r', (?!\")|\s+\<br\>',
             engine='python').dropna(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2                        col3
0  name  date                    ["data"]
1  name  date  ["data", "data2", "data3"]
2  name  date          ["data1", "data2"]
```